# Adding label values for easyalluvial alluvial_wide in r

Tags: r, sankey-diagram

I'm looking to label the "flow" portion of alluvial diagram created with alluvial_wide from easyalluvial package. How much goes into each flows connecting the stratum. 
I`m aware of this issue where ggplot and ggalluvial is used but I wanted to do it with easyalluvial

([How to add value labels on the flows item of a Alluvial/Sankey plot (on R ggalluvial)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57745314/how-to-add-value-labels-on-the-flows-item-of-a-alluvial-sankey-plot-on-r-ggallu)

Any clue on this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for using easyalluvial. I am the author of the package. Currently there is no feature for labelling the flows. All labels must be placed within the stratum. You can try `parcats::parcats` to convert the `easyalluvial` plot to plotly/D3 then you can hover over the flow with your mouse and you will get the count in the tooltip.

https://erblast.github.io/parcats/articles/parcats.html